# Ubuntu dual boot in SSd

Tags: ubuntu, installation

Well, today a downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 from Ubuntu's website and created my bootable pendrive to configure a dual boot in my notebook. The problem is that I don't have enough space the main drive (C:) so I created a new partition in the D: drive to install Ubuntu. But when I booted in the pendrive I wasn't able to find this new partition that I've created because the installer showed the hole drive as one only partition. So I wanted to know how can I install Ubuntu in a second drive.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install just a live boot from your C partition you must do it with EasyBCD you can check that in youtube, but its just a live boot.

Answer (score 0):

check your partition file system for Ubuntu installation because FAT and NTFS file systems are pretty old school and have compatibility issues. So to install you need to change your file system for that partition.[check here for more](https://superuser.com/questions/782849/can-ubuntu-linux-be-installed-on-fat32-or-ntfs)